# OTA for esp32 using ethernet checksum failed

Tags: arduino, ethernet, esp32, atmega

I'm using *Atmega2560* connected to Ethernet module to get binary file of *Esp32* then send the file through UART to Esp32 to update it's firmware.

I'm trying to get binary file data through Ethernet module using HttpClient library but when the data stored in Esp32 OTA partition, then I'm getting:

```
esp_image: Checksum failed . Calculated 0xad read 0x0
```

When i checked some of the received data from the binary file before being sent to esp32, i can see that some location have `0x0` instead of the right value it should be.

That's part of my code where i read the binary file and sent it to Esp32.

```
EthernetClient transport;
HttpClient client(transport, SERVER, SERVER_PORT);
Serial.print("Check for update file ");
Serial.println(PATH);
client.get(PATH);
int statusCode = client.responseStatusCode();
Serial.print("Update status code: ");
Serial.println(statusCode);
if (statusCode != 200)
{
client.stop();
return;
}
long bin_length = client.contentLength();
if (bin_length == HttpClient::kNoContentLengthHeader) {
client.stop();
Serial.println("Server didn't provide Content-length header. Can't continue with update.");
return;
}
Serial.print("Server returned update file of size ");
Serial.print(bin_length);
Serial.println(" bytes");
ESPSerial.print(String(bin_length)); //send file size to ESP
delay(10000);
byte data_char;
int counter=0;
while (bin_length > 0)
{
if (!client.readBytes(&data_char, 1)) // reading a byte with timeout
break;
ESPSerial.write(data_char); //here send data to esp32
if(bin_length==0||bin_length==1||bin_length==2){Serial.print("last data=");Serial.println(data_char,HEX);}
counter++;
if(counter==1000)
{
Serial.println(bin_length);
counter=0;
delay(100);
}
bin_length--;
}
client.stop();
if (bin_length > 0)
{
Serial.print("Timeout downloading update file at ");
Serial.print(bin_length);
Serial.println(" bytes. Can't continue with update.");
return;
}
```

Anyone could help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the ESP32 board, it turns out that it's a power supply problem since during the OTA the Wifi consumes more current.

Make sure your battery is charged or use a big capacitor across the Power supply lines to keep the voltage high during the OTA process.